# When I use JSch, can I use custom OutputStream with the socket?

Tags: java, sockets, io, jsch, outputstream

When I use JSch lib, can I use custom `OutputStream`?

I want to wrap JSch message with Google Proto. So I have to use custom `OutputStream`.

I knew that JSch could set custom `SocketFactory`. So I made a custom `SocketFactory`.

But when session is connected, it was frozen. It didn't work.

I think that my custom `OutputStream` interrupted communication with SSH protocol.

```
Session session = jSch.getSession( "root", "localhost", 55000 );
session.setPassword( "root" );
session.setConfig( "StrictHostKeyChecking","no" );
session.setSocketFactory( new SocketFactory() {
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket( String host, int port ) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {

        return new Socket( host, port );
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream( Socket socket ) throws IOException {

        return socket.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream( Socket socket ) throws IOException {

        return new CustomOutputStream();
    }
} );
session.connect();
```

And here is my custom stream.

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    @Override
    public void write( int b ) throws IOException {
        byte[] a = new byte[] { (byte) b };
        write(a, 0, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void write( byte[] b, int off, int len ) throws IOException {
        System.out.println( b.hashCode() );

        // Todo
        //  JschProto.JschContents jschContents = // JschProto.JschContents.newBuilder().setContent( ByteString.copyFrom( b ) )
        //              .setType( "t" )
        //              .build();

        super.write(b, off, len);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CustomOutputStream` doesn't use the socket. Here's an example of how you could incorporate it into your design.

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private OutputStream innerStream;

    public CustomOutputStream(Socket socket) {
      this(socket.getOutputStream);
    }

    public CustomOutputStream(OutputStream delegate) {
      this.innerStream = delegate;
    }

    //TODO: Override more methods to delegate to innerStream

    @Override
    public void write( int b ) throws IOException {
        byte[] a = new byte[] { (byte) b };
        write(a, 0, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void write( byte[] b, int off, int len ) throws IOException {


        System.out.println( b.hashCode() );

// Todo
    //  JschProto.JschContents jschContents = // JschProto.JschContents.newBuilder().setContent( ByteString.copyFrom( b ) )
//              .setType( "t" )
//              .build();

        innerStream.write(b, off, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I resolve this problem with your solution.